# set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 doesn't work

Tags: magento2, php, apache

I got a big problem. When I first installed Magento I got the error set `always_populate_raw_post_data to -1`, which I did and it worked.

Now I am trying to install some sample data into Magento and for that, I need to install the plugin called Magento_CatalogSampleData. So when I am trying to install it I get the same error again that I got during the installation of the Magento application `always_populate_raw_post_data to -1`.

I have set it to `always_populate_raw_post_data` -1, both in the php.ini but also added `php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1` in the Apache2 config. But still get the same error during the readiness check.

How to solve this, I have no clue?[image]

Comment: You set `always_populate_raw_post_data=-1` in `php.ini`, Are you restart Apache2 ?

Comment: Yes I have don that. I changed the `php.ini` in `etc/php5/apache2` and have `always_populate_raw_post_data 1`

Comment: I think your path with `php.ini` incorrect. You need using `phpinfo()` find path correct

Comment: Unfortunately it was the right path

Comment: What's you php version?

Comment: "PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:13:10).Zend Engine v2.6.0, with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev @YiorgosMoschovitis

Comment: How about adding php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1 in your .htaccess file?

Comment: How do I correctly add this kind of line php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1 in the right way to .htacess? never done any kind of modification in this file in my life actually. @YiorgosMoschovitis

Comment: Uncomment  always_populate_raw_post_data=-1 in php.ini located in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\php.ini works for me

Answer (score 6):

As of PHP 5.6.0 `always_populate_raw_post_data` is deprecated and is commented out. So this value always equals 0 in php.ini

In order to override this you have two options

### **1. If you are using CGI/FCGI**

Refer to your phpinfo(), find the value for 'user_ini.filename'. It should be sth like .user.ini or php.ini

In your web root create a file with the filename you found above, (e.g. .user.ini). If it's already there open it with a text editor.

In it add the line

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

### 2. If not

Open your .htaccess file with a text editor.

Add the following code

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

---

You can read [this](https://www.saotn.org/magento-20-php-ini-always_populate_raw_post_data-setting/) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: No need to add .htaccess, I just add always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 bottom of php.ini & restart my apache that working

Comment: As I wrote, I did this....

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.6.0 and above does not support always_populate_raw_post_data, so it need to be set to -1.

This is the common error  faced during Magento 2.0 installation.
**Setp 1: Find out the PHP version and Server API** 
Create a file phpinfo.php file and paste in there the following code.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Go to your browser and access the above created file, this should display the infomation about php  used.

PHP can run in one of two ways-
1->within Apache as an Apache module (mod_php) or 
2->as a separate executable along with Apache through Common Gateway Interface (CGI, FastCGI).

In order to identify the server API(i.e CGI or Apache Module), Look for the Value under Server API Column.

**for CGI based, Follow the instructions below.**

Look for the file name under the "Additional .ini files parsed"  as highlighted in the picture below.
[image]

Create a file with the same name(in my case it is alt_php.ini) under your root folder(i.e Public_Html) and add the following code.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Just save the file and  you are done. It should work

**For Apche Module based,** 
Add the following code  to your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As I wrote, I did this...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it works after replacing php_flag by php_value:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

http://piwik262.rssing.com/chan-56203786/latest.php#item5

(that was in my case)

Answer (score 1):

I got this when installing magento. For me, nothing worked. I tried setting the `always_populate_raw_post_data` in (correct) `php.ini`, and even inside `.htaccess`. Finally, I was able to install magento through the command-line-interface. I had run the following command (change the values to match your environment):

```
magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/shop/"  --db-host="localhost" --db-name="shop" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="Magento" --admin-lastname="Admin" --admin-email="thcdesigning@gmail.com" --admin-user="gogol" --admin-password="gogol123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1"
```

To find out more about setting-up through cli, [read this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#install-cli-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to open php.ini as an administrator, after that to change all you need in the file and after that restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find the path of `php.ini` configuration file. You can find `php.ini` file path by using `phpinfo()`. Once you find the path of file. Go to that path and open the file and find `always_populate_raw_post_data` and set `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` save and restart the server.

if the issue still not gone you can add the `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` in your .htaccess file which is located at the root directory of Magento then restart the server.

Now this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create file: .user.ini
Add this line in file: always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

restart setting Magento

Wooala!

Only this was help me to prevent installing error.

Comment: As I wrote, I did this....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I have php 5.6. Under root i have directory apache2 which contain php.ini and directory cli with php.ini.
 All changes earned only apache2/php.ini and this resolve my problem.

Comment: As I wrote, I did this....

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Magento!

Open `user.ini` from the root folder and add below line at bottom of the file.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Problem solved, Enjoy!

Comment: Read the post and you see what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I use MAMP the php config is overwritten and you need to edit the template to have the `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1`

> File->Edit Template -> PHP -> PHP XX

Comment: As I wrote, I did this....

Answer (score -1):

It works, you just have to add the one line in `.user.ini` file :

> ```
> memory_limit = 768M
> max_execution_time = 18000
> session.auto_start = off
> suhosin.session.cryptua = off
>
> memory_limit = 768M
> max_execution_time = 18000
> session.auto_start = off
> suhosin.session.cryptua = off
> always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
> ```