# Magento2 : Installation error of always_populate_raw_post_data

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install Magento 2 and I have php version 5.6 in my system. 
When I click on `Start Readiness Check` , it is displaying error of `PHP Settings Check *`. I uncommented `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `-1` and restart my apache also but still I am getting same error.

Can anyone help me in this Urgently.

Comment: open the `proper php.ini` file which you can see after running phpinfo(), uncomment the line `always_populate_raw_post_data`. Then remove cache from var/cache and then again run readiness check.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Yes i am doing in same way but still this error exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all solution related to `always_populate_raw_post_data` but it didn't help me so in the last I skipped this validation. I removed `disabled` tag from the element using **Inspect Element** , So i was able to proceed further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create info.php file with following content.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Run that file and check there **Loaded Configuration Files**. Now edit that php.ini file to set always_populate_raw_post_data value to given value and restart apache.

Comment: yes i checked from phpinfo() only and it return `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini ` but still not working

Comment: Are you doing in local system or in web server ?

Comment: i am doing in Local system

Comment: Go to this solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93465/set-always-populate-raw-post-data-to-1-doesnt-work

Comment: Okay.  Did you try after clearing browser cache or in private window ?

Comment: in private window also getting same issue , even after clear browser cache also.

Comment: Okay. Try using .htaccess and .user.ini file in Magento 2 root directory.

Comment: @KishanPatadia I tried with .htaccess but still same issue and where is .user.ini file ?

Comment: Create .user.ini file in root directory of Magento 2 as follows.

memory_limit = 768M
max_execution_time = 18000
session.auto_start = off
suhosin.session.cryptua = off
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Comment: sorry. please write every variable and value in new line

Comment: @KishanPatadia i added .user.ini file in m2 root and clear cache but stil this issue exists

Comment: @KishanPatadia do you have command line query for m2 installation ?

Comment: @BornCoder, you can install m2 using composer `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition`